# iOS SVPullToRefresh "Load more" and "Refresh" at the same time

Tags: ios, pull-to-refresh

When the tableView's data source contains a few objects , in other words the data source can't fill full of the tableView then pull to refresh , it will trigger "Load more" and "Refresh" at the same time.How can I fix this?

http://youtu.be/ntza9pqUmn0

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out!This works! Thanks!

https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh/issues/149